# Multiple timerange group in days of data

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to get the first and last document of three different time ranges within 24 hours and then group it by days.

Time Ranges in a day

Day 1

T1 : 06:00 - 17:00 - Get the first and last document

T2 : 17:00 - 22:00 - Get the first and last document

T3 : 22:00 - 06:00 - Get the first and last document

Day 2.. so on

**Sample Document**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5ba6bc27260d0909e43b0874"), 
"_DeviceName" : "Ground Floor", 
"PointType" : "Building", 
"_DeviceID" : ObjectId("5b9ae3a76080700be0f173d6"), 
"_TariffID" : ObjectId("5a8893216b41bd32c0797f91"), 
"_Timestamp" : ISODate("2018-09-22T22:03:18.552+0000"), 
"_ModbusID" : 1, 
"_LocationID" : ObjectId("5b9ae0eb6080700be0f173bf"),
"Registers" : {
    "quadrant4reactiveenergyL3" : 781.0, 
    "quadrant4reactiveenergyL2" : 74.0, 
    "quadrant4reactiveenergyL1" : 144.0, 
    "quadrant1reactiveenergyL3" : 52.0, 
    "quadrant1reactiveenergyL2" : 706.0, 
    "quadrant1reactiveenergyL1" : 185.0, 
    "totalharmonicdistorsionVL3" : 3.3000000000000003, 
    "totalharmonicdistorsionVL2" : 3.5, 
    "totalharmonicdistorsionVL1" : 3.6, 
    "consumedactiveenergyL3" : 9144.0, 
    "consumedactiveenergyL2" : 21774.0, 
    "consumedactiveenergyL1" : 18509.0, 
    "totalconsumedactiveenergy" : 49445.0, 
}}
```

What I tried to do is the following;
Grouped by time but cannot get the first and last element for each cond.

```
"$project": {
            "yearMonthDayUTC": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                    "date": "$_Timestamp"
                }
            },
            "timewithOffset": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%H:%M:%S",
                    "date": "$_Timestamp"
                }
            },
            "Registers.totalconsumedactiveenergy": 1.0,
            "_DeviceID": 1.0
        }
"$group": {
            "_id": {
                "Date": "$yearMonthDayUTC",
                "Device": "$_DeviceID"
            },
            "T1": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$and": [
                                {
                                    "$gte": [
                                        "$timewithOffset",
                                        "06:00:00"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$lte": [
                                        "$timewithOffset",
                                        "17:00:00"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        1.0,
                        0.0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "T2": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$and": [
                                {
                                    "$gte": [
                                        "$timewithOffset",
                                        "17:00:00"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$lte": [
                                        "$timewithOffset",
                                        "22:00:00"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        1.0,
                        0.0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "firstactive": {
                "$first": "$$ROOT.Registers.totalconsumedactiveenergy"
            },
            "lastactive": {
                "$last": "$$ROOT.Registers.totalconsumedactiveenergy"
            }
        }
    },
```

I am expecting to see something like this

Day1 : 12.12.2018

T1 - first document , lastdocument

T2 - first document , lastdocument

T3 - first document , lastdocument

Day2 : 13.12.2018

T1 - first document , lastdocument

T2 - first document , lastdocument

T3 - first document , lastdocument

...

Comment: can you post sample documents?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: the posted document doesn't have yearMonthDayUTC and timewithOffset fields

Comment: Okay added the project stage in the query code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below aggregation pipeline, if you want the complete `$first` and `$last` documents you need to use `$$ROOT`

```
db.t18.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id : {
        date : {$dateToString: {format : "%Y-%m-%d", date : "$_Timestamp"}}, 
        T : {$switch : 
            {branches: [
                {case: {$and: [{$gte : [{$hour : "$_Timestamp"}, 6]},{$lt : [{$hour : "$_Timestamp"}, 17]}]}, then : "T1"},
                {case: {$and: [{$gte : [{$hour : "$_Timestamp"}, 17]},{$lt : [{$hour : "$_Timestamp"}, 22]}]}, then : "T2"}
            ],
            default : "T3"
        }}},
        firstactive : {$first : "$Registers.totalconsumedactiveenergy"},
        lastactive : {$last : "$Registers.totalconsumedactiveenergy"}
    }},
    {$group: {_id : {date : "$_id.date"}, data : {$push : {"k" : "$_id.T", "v" : ["$firstactive","$lastactive"]}}}},
    {$project: {_id : 0, date : "$_id.date", "data" : {$arrayToObject : "$data"}}}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, really. I guess one thing is confusing the aggregation is that the documents have different devices with similar meter data that also needs to be grouped by "_DeviceID" so each device would have their own date and time ranges. Would that be possible to add that too?

"_id" : { "date" : "2018-12-31", "T" : "T1" }, "firstactive" : 499796233.0, "lastactive" : 22693981.0 that's what I get, you can see lastactive is lower than the firstactive, it is because probably reading it from another device's data

Comment: you can add `_DeviceID` in `$group` _id field and also you can pre `$sort` by `_Timestamp`